# Service Broker ,message arrives target server but it stays at sender queue

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am using SQL server 2012 at sender and receiver's service broker

and i have the following contract and message on both

```
create MESSAGE TYPE [//Photo/Message] 
    VALIDATION = NONE


create CONTRACT [//photo/Contract]
    ([//Photo/Message]  SENT BY INITIATOR)
```

at sender:

```
create SERVICE [tcp://192.168.4.173:4022/HadoopSender/Audit/HadoopDataSender] 
    AUTHORIZATION dbo
    ON QUEUE dbo.HadoopInitiatorAuditQueue -
```

i have created the route at receiver as

```
create ROUTE [RouteDataReceiver] WITH ADDRESS = N'TRANSPORT'
```

when i issue send message from sender ,it reaches target server's queue but it stays at `sys.transmission_queue` at sender 
why this message is not deleted from sender queue `sys.transmission_queue`

is there any configuration that i should apply ?

Comment: Is there a route at the Target back to the initiator? I've sec what you describe when that isn't set up.

Comment: there is a route from initiator to target as following with sender certificate ,and at target there is the following route create ROUTE [RouteDataReceiver]
 WITH ADDRESS = N'TRANSPORT'

Comment: i have read that an acknowledgment should be sent from receiver to sender in order to ask the sender to delete the message from  sys.transmission_queue ,how can i know why this acknowledgment  is not sent

Answer (score 0):

because the route at receiver is transport

service at sender should be renamed as following [tcp://MachineName:PORT/UniqueServiceName]

in order to let receiver service knows which IP it should send the acknowledgment to

Comment: Renamed? Or have it's address at to that value? The name of the route shouldn't have any bearing on how it functions while the address certainly does.